# How to enlarge image while hover over an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show the thumbnail image large when hover over it, similar to the one in

http://www.freelayouts.com/websites/html-templates  Plz help. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a tooltip plugin. There are plenty of them.
Check out this list: https://cssauthor.com/jquery-css3-hover-effects/

Comment: Both links are down.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Replaced broken links with a plugin overview page.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img class="enlarge-onhover" src="img.jpg">

...

And on the css:

.enlarge-onhover {
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
}

.enlarge-onhover:hover {
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://fancybox.net/blog

Fancybox looks nice, uses JQuery and is highly configurable with various show/hide effects. Tutorial number 3 on this page shows you how to use it OnHover rather than OnClick

The home page http://fancybox.net/home shows some examples of the visual effect

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function bigImg(x) {
   x.style.height = "64px";
   x.style.width = "64px";
}

function normalImg(x) {
   x.style.height = "32px";
   x.style.width = "32px";
}
</script>

<img onmouseover="bigImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" width="32" height="32">
```

The function `bigImg()` is triggered when the user mouse over the image. This function enlarges the image.

The function `normalImg()` is triggered when the mouse pointer is moved out of the image. That function sets the height and width of the image back to normal.